# .addEventListener() não é uma função

Tags: javascript, funções, eventos

Estou montando um script para modais, porém aconteceu um erro inesperado, o console diz:

> Uncaught TypeError: loginBtn.addEventListener is not a function`", "at modaisGeral (index.html:233)" e "at index.html:235",

Como posso corrigir?

```
function modaisGeral(){
    var principalModal = document.querySelector("modais");//Recebe um elemento
    var loginBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".login-modal-open");//Recebe um array de elementos
    var loginModal = document.getElementById("login-modal");//Recebe o modal de login

    loginBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){});

}modaisGeral();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`document.querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) retorna uma **lista de elementos** e não um elemento propriamente dito.

Logo, `loginBtn` é um *array* e não é possível adicionar um `eventListener` em um *array*.

Se você quer adicionar o mesmo `eventListener` **para todos os elementos** deste *array*, vai precisar fazer um loop nos elementos e adicioná-lo.

```js
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.login-modal-open');

for(var el of elementos){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id);
  });
}
```

```html
<a id="1" class="login-modal-open" href="#">Link 1</a>
<img id="2" class="login-modal-open"src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
<button id="3" class="login-modal-open">Botão 3</button>
<button id="4" class="login-modal-open">Botão 4</button>
<a id="5" class="login-modal-open" href="#">Link 5</button>
```

Comment: Obg, valeu pela prontidão :D

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @jbueno https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199222/13469

Você teria que escolher qual índice desse `array` você iria adicionar o evento, por exemplo:

```
loginBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function(){});
```

Assim você iria adicionar o evento ao primeiro elemento encontrado que possui a classe informada.

Para adicionar o evento à todos os elementos que correspondem ao `document.querySelectorAll`, você poderia fazer assim:

```
for (var i = 0; i < loginBtn.length; i++)
  loginBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {alert('Funcionou!')});
```

Comment: Obrigado man :D