# Preciso de ajuda com a função textContent

Tags: javascript

Tenho que fazer a validação de todas as `<td>` de `<tr>` através do *Javascript*, para um projeto da faculdade!

Usei o seguinte código:

```js
var dvd = document.querySelector(".info-dvd");
var dvdInfo = dvd.textContent;
if (dvdInfo == "Sim" || dvdInfo == "Não") {
  console.log("tudo funcionando");
} else {
  dvd.textContent = "Preecha o campo com Sim ou Não";
  console.log("campo invalido");
}
if (dvdInfo == "") {
  dvd.textContent = "O Campo não pode estar vazio!"
  console.log("campo está vazio");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Filmes Assistidos</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Listas de Filmes Assistidos</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="container">
      <h2>Filmes</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th class="changeth">Nome</th>
            <th class="changeth">Gênero</th>
            <th class="changeth">Possui DVD</th>
            <th class="dimas">Dimas</th>
            <th class="bruna">Bruna</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabela-pacientes">
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal 1</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">A</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal 2</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">ZS</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">O Exorcista</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">AAAAA</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Jogos Vorazes</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Ação/Ficção científica</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">A Hora do Pesadelo</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">UM Príncepe em Nova York</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Comédia</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="total">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="bg-success total">Total:</td>

            <td class="bg-dark info-total">0</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="avatar" src="img/bruna.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="avatar" src="img/dimas.png" alt="dimas.png">
          </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark">
      <h3 class="custom">Copyright @ Brumas</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="js/principal.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Até ai tudo bem, só que ele só valida a primeira `<td>` as demais ele não valida, se houver algum erro ele passa direto, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: mostre seu html também

Comment: Desculpa!!!
Obrigado pela dica!!!

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199218/addeventlistener-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando faz a consulta com seletores usando [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) é retornado apenas primeiro elemento dentro do documento corresponde ao seletor especificado.
Por conta disso o seu código opera apenas no primeiro elemento cujo a classe é `.info-dvd`.

Para modificar esse comportamento use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que ao invés de retornar o primeiro elemento `Document.querySelectorAll()` retorna uma lista de todos os elementos presentes no documento que coincidam com o grupo de seletores especificado.

Depois que obtiver a lista de todos os elementos cujo a classe é `.info-dvd`, use um [laço de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Lacos_e_iteracoes) ou o método [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) para iterar pelos elementos da lista e executar as ações necessárias a suas regra de negócios.

```js
//Retorna a lista de todos os elementos que combinam com o critério de busca.
var dvd = document.querySelectorAll(".info-dvd");
//Para cada elemento retornado executa uma ação dependendo do seu conteúdo.
dvd.forEach((e) => {
  var dvdInfo = e.textContent;
  switch (dvdInfo) {  //Troquei os if por um controle de fluxo switch por questão de legibilidade
    case "Sim": //fall through case para dvdInfo == "Sim" || dvdInfo == "Não".
    case "Não":
                 console.log("tudo funcionando");
                 break;
    case "":
                 e.textContent = "O Campo não pode estar vazio!"
                 console.log("campo está vazio");
                 break;
    default:
                 e.textContent = "Preecha o campo com Sim ou Não";
                 console.log("campo invalido");
                 break;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Filmes Assistidos</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Listas de Filmes Assistidos</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="container">
      <h2>Filmes</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th class="changeth">Nome</th>
            <th class="changeth">Gênero</th>
            <th class="changeth">Possui DVD</th>
            <th class="dimas">Dimas</th>
            <th class="bruna">Bruna</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabela-pacientes">
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal 1</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">A</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal 2</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">ZS</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">O Exorcista</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">AAAAA</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">Jogos Vorazes</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Ação/Ficção científica</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">A Hora do Pesadelo</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="filmes">
            <td class="info-nome">UM Príncepe em Nova York</td>
            <td class="info-genero">Comédia</td>
            <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
            <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
            <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="total">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="bg-success total">Total:</td>

            <td class="bg-dark info-total">0</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="avatar" src="img/bruna.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="avatar" src="img/dimas.png" alt="dimas.png">
          </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark">
      <h3 class="custom">Copyright @ Brumas</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="js/principal.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cara simplesmente incrível!
Estou aprendendo Javascript ainda, comecei a estudar ontem!
Ajudou e muito!!!!!