# Tratar retorno parseInt

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando meus estudo em JavaScript e me deparei com uma questão que é pegar o valor (monetário) em uma classe html, tratar e exibir o resultado sem R$ em outro elemento html. Porém não funcionou.

Código:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementsByClassName("entrada");
  // var test = 'R$ 299,00';

  function getMoney( str )
  {
          return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
  }
  function formatReal( int )
  {
          var tmp = int+'';
          tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
          if( tmp.length > 6 )
                  tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

          return tmp;
  }


  var int = getMoney( test );
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = (formatReal( int ));

}
```

```html
<p>Valor do item: <strong class="entrada">R$ 229,00</strong></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Clique para tratar</button>

<p>Valor tratado: <span style="color:red" id="saida"></span></p>
```

Comment: Em `getMoney(test)`, `test` é um `NodeList` (retornado por `getElementsByClassName`). Portanto, como `replace` é um método de strings, você não poderá o obter a partir de uma instância de `NodeList`. Você precisa obter o valor do elemento, isto é, uma string. Talvez **[esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478685/69296)** possa te dar uma ideia adicional desse problema e te dar algumas ideias de como resolvê-lo. :-)

Comment: Mas no meu caso Luiz nao preciso de laço... o valor já está em um elemento. Não entendi.

Comment: Ele quis dizer que sua função espera uma string, mas você está passando uma lista de elementos do DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É como o nosso amigo já falou nos comentários. Você está passando para a sua função getMoney uma nodeList. Essa nodeList é o retorno da função nativa do javascript "**document.getElementsByClassName()**".

Quando você usa essa função diretamente, ela retorna todos os elementos do DOM que possuem a classe buscada. Por isso o retorno de uma lista.

Enquanto isso, o seu método getMoney espera receber uma string.

A minha sugestão é... Troque isso:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("entrada");
```

Por isso:

```
var test = document.querySelector(".entrada").innerText;
```

Comment: Oi Jaderson... aquele caso do iniciante que agora não errará, importante é o conceito da coisa. Sua sugestão funcionou, também recebi um força através do trecho abaixo.... forte abraço!

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("skuBestPrice")[0].innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

Muda o teu elemento strong de class, para id, fica mais fácil trabalhar assim, depois vc pega o innerHTML desse elemento e executa sua função.
EX.

```
<body>

<p>Valor do item: <strong id="entrada">R$ 229,00</strong></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Clique para tratar</button>

<p>Valor tratado: <span style="color:red" id="saida"></span></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementById("entrada").innerHTML;
  // var test = 'R$ 299,00';

  function getMoney( str )
  {
          return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
  }
  function formatReal( int )
  {
          var tmp = int+'';
          tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
          if( tmp.length > 6 )
                  tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

          return tmp;
  }


  var int = getMoney( test );
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = (formatReal( int ));

}
</script>
</body>
```